# Error- StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 4

Tags: java

I am writing a basic code that will check if a tweet contains a hashtag or mention, and if either have a space or tab following, then it will not count. I'm also getting an 'unclosed character literal' message and I'm not sure why.

```
    for (int i=0; i < tweet.length(); i++) {

      char currentchar = tweet.charAt(i);
      char nextcar = tweet.charAt(i+1);

      if (currentchar == '#') {

        if (! (nextcar == ' ') && ! (nextcar == '/t')) {

        numofhashtags++; 

        } 
      }
       if (currentchar == '@') {

         if ((nextcar != ' ') && (nextcar != '/t')) {

        numofmentions++;
         }

       }
     }
```

Comment: `i < tweet.length()` This loops til the last char, so what do you expect to get at `char nextcar = tweet.charAt(i+1);`? There is nothing beyond that last char. Btw: `'/t'` ... this is not how one escapes something.

Comment: Do you understand what the error message mean?

Answer (score 0):

First of all when you post code, please post what the string value of tweet is.

The problem in your code is this:

```
for (int i=0; i < tweet.length(); i++) {

      char currentchar = tweet.charAt(i);
      char nextcar = tweet.charAt(i+1);//<-- here
```

For now let us assume the string length is 3.

You start counting the string from 0th location to 3rd location. When you do `i+1`, you are trying to access 4th index of the string which does not exists.

Also use `"\t"` to check for tab not `"/t"`

Possible way of how you can change your loop is:

```
for (int i=1; i <tweet.length(); i++) {//change i=1 and condition to <=

      char currentchar = tweet.charAt(i-1);//since we are already accessing from the next character you will you have scan the previous character for current character by doing i-1
      char nextcar = tweet.charAt(i);// you will already have next character access so no need of i+1
```

Comment: Why change the condition in the first line from `<` to `<=`?

Comment: @ShreyasSarvothama *"How can i do this"* I don't know, but you did it :P. Glad that you've fixed it.

Comment: @Tom haha.. Cheers Tom

Answer (score 0):

Make your `for-loop` in this form:

```
 for (int i=0; i < tweet.length()-1; i++)
```